# Como usar Join ou Aggregate em consulta SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

Ao realizar a consulta em uma determinada tabela, `numOrc` é uma lista que pode conter um ou mais valores.

Então, precisava concatenar esses valores em uma unica  `string`, utilizando `;` como limitador.

Então tentei:

```
var model = (from s in db.Vendas_pedidos
                     join p in db.Cliente_contatos on s.idContato equals p.id_cliente_contato into _p
                     from p in _p.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join t in (
                             from t1 in db.Vendas_itens
                             group t1 by t1.numeroPedido into g
                             select new
                             {
                                 numeroPed = g.Key,
                                 valorTotal = g.Sum(x => x.valortotal),
                                 maxStatus = g.Max(x => x.status),
                                 tipoMaterial = g.Max(x => x.tipoElemento),
                                 numOrc = g.Select(x => x.numOrc)
                             }
                             ) on s.id equals t.numeroPed
                     where s.idCliente == codCliente
                     select new
                     {
                         id = s.id,
                         dataCad = s.dataEmissao,
                         contato = (p.nome + " " + p.sobrenome),
                         valorTotal = ("R$ " + t.valorTotal.ToString()),
                         dataSolicCotacao = s.dataSolicCotacao,
                         status = t.maxStatus,
                         tipoMaterial = (t.tipoMaterial.ToString().Equals("5") ? "Serviço" : "Venda").ToString(),
                         numOrc = t.numOrc.ToList().Aggregate((a, b) => a + ";" + b)
                     }).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).ToList();
```

Porém ao executar é retornado o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Por que não fazer:

```
numOrc = string.Join(";", t.numOrc)
```

em vez de:

```
numOrc = t.numOrc.ToList().Aggregate((a, b) => a + ";" + b)
```

?